# Strip lines on SPC Charts

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to create a chart with upper and lower control limits. I was trying to achieve a similar look to the 1st image where the upper and lower controls are a block rather than my effort, image 2, where I've just made a thick line.

I have seen a few a ways on how to do this and have applied it with a degree of success, but the main issue I'm having is if you look at my second image, you will see the upper and lower controls fluctuate.  All the examples I've seen just show the strip lines as straight lines. Is there a way of doing this?

For my lower control I have tried inputting in the 'Strip Width Type' the expression 
     =Fields!LowerControl.value

but this still just gives a straight line

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***EDIT*** Going with Pete's answer below I am struggling to plot the upper control using a range chart. Could someone direct me where I'm going wrong please?

[image]

[image]

---

I'm not aware of a way to dynamically size a StripLine. However, if you have data for what the controls should be at each date, you can plot it on your chart like any other data.

Include what the controls should be along with each value of your SQL dataset, e.g.:

```
SELECT
    a_date, a_value,
    CASE WHEN a_date <= '01-MAR-2017' THEN 25 ELSE 30 END lower_control,
    CASE WHEN a_date <= '01-MAR-2017' THEN 50 ELSE 55 END mid_control,
    CASE WHEN a_date <= '01-MAR-2017' THEN 75 ELSE 80 END upper_control
FROM
    a_table
```

If a simple line will suffice for your controls, you can add each control to the Values as a Chart Series, with the appropriate formatting.

[image]

If you want your controls to cover a larger area, you can plot this using a Range chart.
[image]

**Edit:** For your upper control range you'll need to set both Top and Bottom values. The Bottom value is from your `uppercontrol` data, and the Top value is the maximum on your Y axis. (E.g. In the above chart I set both the Y axis maximum and the `uppercontrol` top to 100.)

Also be aware of the order of your ranges. Either have your data line first so it appears over each control, or give your controls a colour with some transparency.

Comment: Appreciate the detailed answer, don't think I will be able to use this method with what I'm working with unfortunately.

Comment: It would be help us help you if you let us know what you don't like about @Pete's answer.  Do you have no control over the dataset?

Comment: I guess I was hoping there was going to be a less time consuming way where I could just put my 'lower control' field in to an expression. It looks like this is the only way to do it and I will accept this as the correct answer. One thing I'm struggling with is the upper control in a range chart, how do I get it to fill from the top down?

Comment: @whitz11 I've now added some notes on upper controls, which should help you create something similar to my range examples.